# Form input not working in Workflow (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

**Disclaimer: I am new to PowerShell and self-taught. If I am using incorrect nomenclature, I apologise.**

PSVersion: 5.1
Host: Server2016

Goal: Creating a user-driven domain controller provisioning script for on-site deployment.

Hi All,

I'm trying to get input from a text box into a workflow in order to rename a server and reboot then continue where the script left off. When I attempt the rename I receive the following error:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'NewName'. The argument is null
>   or empty.

**Code :**

```
$Handler_OK_Button_Click =
{
    [string]$FieldUsrNm = $TextBoxUsrNm.Text
    [string]$FieldPwd = $TextBoxPwd.Text
    [string]$FieldSn = $TextBoxSn.Text

    if (($FieldUsrNm -eq "") -or ($FieldPwd -eq "") -or ($FieldSn -eq "")) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please Enter The Missing Information.", "Data")
    }

    else {

        #Start Rename Workflow
        Workflow RenameSvr {
            Param (
                [string]$FieldSn
            )

            #Rename Computer
            InlineScript {Rename-Computer -NewName $Using:FieldSn -Force}

        }
        RenameSvr

        #Closes Form
        $FormMain.Close()
    }
}
```

Code has been removed from the above to make it easier to read.

I can perform this task using a function, it works. So I know that the string value is being passed.

If anyone can point out what I am doing wrong, it is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure FieldSn is not null? Debug your code or print that value.

Comment: Yep, FieldSn isn't null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass the `-FieldSn` parameter in the `RenameSvr` Workflow so value is empty.

In the `Else` statement replace (just after the workflow) by : `RenameSvr -FieldSn $FieldSn` so that the workflow receives the value :

```
$Handler_OK_Button_Click =
{
    [string]$FieldUsrNm = $TextBoxUsrNm.Text
    [string]$FieldPwd = $TextBoxPwd.Text
    [string]$FieldSn = $TextBoxSn.Text

    if (($FieldUsrNm -eq "") -or ($FieldPwd -eq "") -or ($FieldSn -eq "")) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please Enter The Missing Information.", "Data")
    }

    else {

        #Start Rename Workflow
        Workflow RenameSvr {
            Param (
                [string]$FieldSn
            )

            #Rename Computer
            InlineScript {Rename-Computer -NewName $Using:FieldSn -Force}

        }
        RenameSvr -FieldSn $FieldSn

        #Closes Form
        $FormMain.Close()
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough @Manu!! You have ended days of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ISE to build this form? Or are you using something like Powershell Studio? In ISE, you can select your lines where are setting the variables and insert a break point using the F9 key. In Powershell Studio, you insert the breakpoint the same way, but you have to switch the mode to run the script in debug mode. Also, you shouldn't need to put the "$Using:" in there. I've not seen that before, but I've used plenty of parameters before.

The things to check here, of course, would be what values are stored in both the $FieldSn and the $TextBoxSn.Text before it actually gets to the Rename-Computer cmdlet. Check to make sure that what is stored in your $TextBoxSn variable is indeed a text box object. Insert a break point at "$FieldSn = $TextBoxSn.Text" and at "InlineScript{Rename-Computer -NewName $Using:FieldSn -Force}" and check the values at that point and let us know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about break points. Huge help!

Write-Output is showing the value, I've taken a screenshot to show the results

[link]https://imgur.com/gYihxpk

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm coming to you from a computer that has too many restrictions on it so that I can't open imgur images...

Comment: All good, here is the output (The break point set at InlineScript)


[DBG]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>> Write-Output $TextBoxSn.Text
ERNFN-8394834

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>> quit


PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Build_DC.ps1
Cancel

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Build_DC.ps1
Hit Line breakpoint on 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Build_DC.ps1:100'
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>> Write-Output $FieldSn
ERNFN-8394834

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>>

Comment: I guess "ERNFN-8394834" is value in the text field? Man, I wish I could see the picture, lol. Also, when I say "check the values at that point," I mean that while it is paused at the break point, you can hover over different variables and it will show you the value inside it. So if you have the breakpoint set at the InlineScript, hover over the "$Using:FieldSn" and it should tell you a value.

Comment: @Joseph _Also, you shouldn't need to put the "$Using:" in there. I've not seen that before, but I've used plenty of parameters before._ This is the way you retrieve variables that are outside of an `InlineScript`

Comment: Ah, that would be why then. I've never done an Inline script. Thanks!